# do the vectors $(1, -1), (2, -1), (3,-1)$ span all of $\mathbb{R}^2\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm thinking that these vectors do **not** span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I say this because a three-dimensional set cannot span a two-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is this the right explanation, or am i missing something? Did i even get the answer correct?

Comment: Three vectors is definitely more than enough to span $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @KennyLau -- Not every three vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $v_1, v_2$ linearly independent, then $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis for $R^2$. So, you just need to verify if your set is linearly independent (which is).

In fact, you only need to take A = $\{(1, -1), (2, -1)\}$ to span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 = 0$

$ \implies a_1 (1, -1) + a_2(2, -1) = (0, 0)$

$\implies (a_1 + 2a_2, -a_1 - a_2) = (0,0)$

Then $a_1 + 2a_2 = 0$ and $-a_1 - a_2 = 0$.

Then, $a_1 = -a_2$ (by second equation) and aplying this in the first equation you get that $-a_2 + 2a_2 = 0$. Then, $a_2 = 0$ and $a_1 = 0$.

Thus, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: can you explain to me how you got the two equations a1 + 2a2 = 0 and -a -a2 = 0? did you somehow use the original vectors?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to be more especific.

Comment: Done! Hope you understand :)

Comment: Just a nitpick. You typed "Spam" but it should be "Span"...

Answer (score 0):

They do because the first two vectors are linearly independent so they form a basis and also span $R^2$.

Comment: how can i determine if a vector is linearly independent?

Comment: the easiest way is the two-by-two determinant is non-zero !

Comment: ok so how can i determine the determinant? is there a formula that i need to be aware of?

Comment: just google "two by two determinant" and lots of examples should pop up.

Comment: ok so if i have determined that a vector is linearly independent.. what does that tell me exactly? and how can i determine if that linearly independent vector spans all of R^2?

Comment: You don’t need to mess with determinants. The only way for a pair of vectors of *any* dimension to be linearly dependent is if one is a scalar multiple of the other.